# Dynamically grow array item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have 3 items and I would like to add them one by one in array.

Firstly, I pass `abc` and it adds abc in `array`, second time, passed `cde`, then `array` removes the first item and add second item `cde`.

But, I would like to add them like `array={abc,cde,...}`

It seems that I need to store previous value. First time, when I add `abc` it looks like `array ={abc}`. Second time, when I add `cde`, `array` should store the previous `abc` value before adding the new one `cde` which looks like `array ={abc,cde,..}`.

Please see this screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

There is no array of the items where I can loop through and add those in another array.

This line always `var array= Arr.push(Arr[0]);` add one item.

```
    var Arr ="";
    var TD;
    function AddData(sVal) {
    var AddRow = true;  
    sVal = Replace(sVal, "~", "%"); 
    Arr = sVal.split("^");                   
            TD.innerHTML = "<INPUT TYPE='HIDDEN' value='" + Arr[0] + "'>";                                  
            TD.innerHTML = Arr[0]; 
            var array= Arr.push(Arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: push accepts an arbitrary amount of args as elements to push into the array. so for example: `arr.push(...[1, 2, 3]); //arr: [1,2,3]` .. it's achieved spreading the array as multiple arguments to pass to push

Comment: Not an answer, but you are missing a bracket somewhere, your `function AddData` is never closed.

Comment: @DiegoD, At one particular time, I am adding only one item like `var array= Arr.push(Arr[0]);`. If I add `abc` then it adds `abc`. It seems like I have to store previous value and add new value. Please provide me an answer.

Comment: @testingtest in my previous comment I was trying to answer to the question that seemed the core issue. But to address the real problem you are having you should be more clear. The code you shared isn't clear and it uses very weird tacticts. You are dealing with the `<tr>` id! why? you are trying to push inside an array its first element? why? that code could be shrinked to few lines if you just meant to push a new row into the target table. I suggest you to just say what exactly your function is supposed to do instead of asking how to add items in group to an array

Comment: @DiegoD, I removed unwanted code. My function should add item in an array. When I say item, it is not an array of items. It is just single item and add it in array. Again, add second item without replacing the first in an array.

Comment: `array.push` just appends an item to the array ***adding*** it. So if you do `arr.push(1); arr.push(2); //arr will be [1, 2]` .. if you do `arr.push(...[1, 2]) //arr will be [1, 2] as well`

Comment: what did you expect from `Arr.push(Arr[0]);`?? don't you see you are taking an array and pushing (so you are adding!) to it its first item. So if `Arr = [1,2,3]; Arr.push(Arr[0]); //Arr: [1,2,3,1]` .. you are not explaining. The code you wrote is nonsense. So please explain the expectation. In general I suggest you strip down what it's not clear in your mind and focus on that only. So instead of involving all that stuff just focus on: `const arr = []; arr.push(1); console.log(arr);`

Comment: Hi @DiegoD, Please see the screenshot. If click on  `Test12` from 1st section then my function adds that in below section. Again, I go and click 2nd item from 1st section, it adds second item in below section. But I would like to store both values in my array which is not happening.

Comment: I updated my answer with a new approach that now deals with source and destination lists

Answer (score 1):

## New approach

I  separated the previous approach from the new one...

#### Having a source list that feeds the destination list when its items get clicked:

Here I show how you can have a `source` list with items feeding a `destination` list:

- When you click on a source list item, it gets appended to the destination as is (cloned)
- At the same time, during the adding operation, the item text content gets appended to a buffer array
- There's also a function that dumps on console an array that lists all the items coming from a given list element (at page load)
- Clicking on an item on destination, it gets removed from the list and from the buffer array
- Items cannot be duplicated on destination so that if you click the first time on a list item in source, it gets appended on destination. The second time it won't have any effect. But after that said item gets removed from destination, it can be added again

```js
const source = document.getElementById('source');
const destination = document.getElementById('destination');

//print on console the list of items in #source as an array of string values
console.log('source list items:', getListItems(source));

//adds the click event listener to the #source list
source
  .addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
    //clicked item
    const target = event.target;
    //if the clicked item is actually a <li>  
    if(target.tagName == 'LI'  && !target.classList.contains('alreadyadded')){
      //calls addItemToList on destination with the current target list item
      addItemToList(destination, target);
      target.classList.add('alreadyadded');
    }
  });

//adds the click event listener to the #destination list
destination
  .addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
    //clicked item
    const target = event.target;
    //if the clicked item is actually a <li>  
    if(target.tagName == 'LI'){
      //removes the class alreadyadded from the corresponding item in the source
      const sourceIndex = target.dataset.sourceIndex;
      source.querySelectorAll('li')[sourceIndex].classList.remove('alreadyadded');  
      //calls addItemToList on destination with the current target list item
      removeItemFromList(target);      
    }
  });

//the array that gets populated by the function addItemToList and cleared by removeItemFromList
const destinationList = [];

//adds a list item to the target list element
function addItemToList(target, item){  
  //gets the index of the item compared to its parent list
  const index = [...item.parentNode.children].indexOf(item);  
  //clones deep the item passed
  const newItem = item.cloneNode(true);
  //sets its data attribute (sourceIndex) with the index of the item in the source list
  newItem.dataset.sourceIndex = index;
  //appends it to target element
  target.append(newItem);
  //updates the buffer array pushing the content of the new item
  destinationList.push(newItem.textContent);
  //logs on console the buffer array
  console.log('buffer array:', destinationList);
}

//removes a list item from its parent
function removeItemFromList(item){  
  //gets the index of the item compared to its parent list
  const index = [...item.parentNode.children].indexOf(item);
  //removes the element from dom
  item.remove();  
  //removes the index element from the destinationList array
  destinationList.splice(index, 1);
  //logs on console the buffer array
  console.log('buffer array:', destinationList);
}

//returns the array of item contents from the target list element
function getListItems(target){
  const listItems = target.querySelectorAll('li');
  return [...listItems].map(li => li.innerText);
}
```

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;  
  padding: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  border-top: solid 1px gray;
}

li{
  border: solid 1px gray;  
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0 1em; 
}

#source li{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#destination li::before{
  content: 'x';
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 0 2px 2px 2px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1ch;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<label>Source:</label>
<ul id="source">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
  <li>test4</li>
</ul>

<label>Destination:</label>
<ul id="destination">  
</ul>
```

## Previous approach

Here follows the previous approach...

#### Pushing an array of values into a target array:

At first it seemed like you needed to push a list of values inside an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
> returns the new length of the array.
>
> push(element0)
>
> push(element0, element1)
>
> push(element0, element1, /* … ,*/ elementN)

```js
const target = [1, 2, 3];
const elementsToAdd = [4, 5, 6];
target.push(...elementsToAdd);

console.log(target); //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

#### Adding a new row to a target table using values from a serialized string:

Trying to further understand your code, I tried to rewrite your `addData` function to limit its action doing what its name suggests (adding data).

Well actually such name could suggest several different actions anyway to shed some light on what exactly did you expect I stripped down its core so that now it just limits itself to ***append*** a new row to the target table using the values coming from a serialized string for its cells.

Those cells will contain an `<input type=hidden>` with the value of the corresponding index from the serialized string. To better show off the otherwise invisible data, I decided also to set the cell innerText with that same value.

***Of course that's not the whole story yet***

```js
//appends 10 rows to the target table
const table = document.getElementById('Table1');
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
  addData(table, 'col~1^col~2^col~3^col~4');
}

//appends a row in target table, with the content coming from raw
function addData(target, raw) {

  //replaces the ~ with % on raw,
  const processed = raw.replaceAll('~', '%'); 
  console.log(processed);
  //and splits its values delimited by ^
  const values = processed.split("^");    
  
  //creates and append a new row in target table
  const newRow = target.insertRow(-1);    

  //for each value in values
  for(value of values){
    //creates a new <input type=hidden>
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    //sets its value as the current value of the array
    input.value = value;            
    
    //creates a new row cell appending the input to its children
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);            
    newCell.append(input);    
    
    //since the only cell content is an hidden input I show it on its content also
    newCell.textContent = value;
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 1rem;
}

table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table tr{
  height: 2rem;
}

table td{
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table id="Table1">
  <tr id="TR01">
    <td>header #1</td>
    <td>header #2</td>
    <td>header #3</td>
    <td>header #4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```